# How fast can I read an ADC of a 2-dimensional array?

Tags: stm32, dma, adc

I have an application where it must control the ADC reading of the array 32x32 element.
For each element I have to choose point - read ADC - turn off ADC. Currently I am using a scanning method like LED scanning. For each scan I read 1 point. Then store the value in the array and transmit it.

However, I found this to be very slow. I want to use DMA to automate this reading, then all I need to do is pass it on.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: With DMA you can automate the transfer of the converted value from ADC to memory and nothing else. I don't understand your application. Do you have to set some GPIOs before every ADC conversion? If you have an ADC channel for every analog value, you can create an automated ADC channel scan with DMA data transfer.

Comment: I read the ADC values of each photocell in the 2 dimensional array. Currently, for each ADC reading, I have to use GPIO to trigger the MUX and read the signal on DEMUX. With this way the CPU has to work a lot.

Comment: Are you using interrupts to signal the end of the ADC conversion? What is your time expectation for one complete measurement cycle and how long is it at the moment?

Comment: I need to transmit 9Kb / s. I don't use interrupts right now and I don't use DMA yet. I see the application of DMA to read multiple channels at the same time. I am reading in the normal way. Select column - select rows - read - store to buffer - when the array is read out, it will be transmitted.
So I asked the question: How do I read - write - pass my array faster.
I'm reaching half the speed I expected

Comment: I don't think DMA will help you in this case. Try to use interrupts to get the end of ADC conversion. This can reduce the time between the measurements. You can go even further and trigger the IO Switch at the "EOSMP" ISR.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your question.

Let's suppose that you want to read data from external signals on the ADC MCU input pin.

I recommend you first, two solutions for ADC Reading that data:

1. Configure your ADC in continuous mode.
2. Configure your ADC in single mode, and configure another peripheral (like timer) that will trigger the ADC to start the conversion at each event.

Second, there are two different way to manage your converted data:

1. After each End Of Conversion Interrupt of the ADC you can store your data manually and do your stuff.

   void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef *AdcHandle)
   {
   /* Get the converted value of regular channel */
   uhADCxConvertedValue = HAL_ADC_GetValue(AdcHandle);
   }
2. Configure a DMA Handler that will deal with the ADC converted data and store it in RAM automatically without the CPU intervention.
   #define ADC_CONVERTED_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE   ((uint32_t)  32)   /* Size of array aADCxConvertedData[] */

static uint16_t   aADCxConvertedData[ADC_CONVERTED_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE];

HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&AdcHandle,uint32_t *)aADCxConvertedData,ADC_CONVERTED_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE

You will find a lot of details in the Reference Manual.

Comment: DMA will have no use here as he wants to decide if he is going to read the voltage for every cell